# Replacing radial fuse with ceramic/glass fuse

Tags: fuses, ceramic

Is it possible to replace a radial fuse T5A 250V with a Glass or Ceramic Fuse 5A 250V?
It's for a power supply for a LED TV.

Comment: I'd be interested in how many times you have already replaced this fuse?

Comment: @Andyaka the comment from nadh_d is meant for you.

Comment: @Andyaka I didn't replace any fuse yet :)

Comment: sorry, I'm new with StackExchange :)

Answer (score 1):

The T in T5A suggests it's a slow acting 5A fuse, using a regular 5A fuse you may see it pop more often when powering on. You're best off replacing like for like.

Answer (score 0):

Electrically, the rating of the fuse is more important than the shape.

You'd need to use a `T 5A 250V` fuse, but yeah if you can fit a  leaded axial fuse and it doesn't foul the nearby components you could use that. Perhaps mounted hairpin style, or maybe you can fit a fuse-holder off board etc.

Comment: The idea to mount a fuse holder on an external panel is a neat idea.  No longer need to open the device to change it.  Obviously such internal safety fuses should not open unless there are other repairs needing to be made but sometimes power line quality is responsible and they can be called nuisance trips.